# How to see execution time for lein tasks

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Is there a way to see executing time for lein goals.
I want something like

lein test

.....

elapsed time: 00:01:35

lein do clean, test

.....

elapsed time: 00:01:59

Comment: *nix has `time` command, that does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

As akond said, on linux or macOS, just use time:

```
> time lein uberjar
lein uberjar   4.82s user  0.99s system  124% cpu  4.671 total
```

I use this all the time (mostly for `lein test`, etc)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, *nix time will provide execution statistics for the entire command.

If you want to drill down and find root cause of a particular performance issue (i.e inefficient test cases) you'll want to create a separate namespace/entry point for profiling with something like [tufte](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/tufte). You can sequence individual functions or entire blocks and get runtime statistics to answer the probable underlying question of "why is x so damn slow?"